# Existence of a linear map using Hahn-Banach theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

Let V and W be Banach spaces and let $T: V \rightarrow W$ and $S: W' \rightarrow V'$ be maps with $f(T(v)) = S(f)(v)$ for all $f \in W', v \in V$. ($V',W'$ are the dual spaces of V and W)

Prove that T is linear and bounded, using the Hahn-Banach theorem.

This exercise appeared in my exam and I had no idea how to prove it. Somehow I find this exercise a little bit strange, but I don't know why.

Comment: It seems that you also need Uniform Boundedness Principle.

Comment: Good question! Who (and why) deducted score?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To show that $T(v_{1}+v_{2})=Tv_{1}+Tv_{2}$ for any $v_{1},v_{2}\in V$:

Prove by contradiction. Suppose the contrary that there exist $v_{1},v_{2}\in V$
such that $T(v_{1}+v_{2})\neq Tv_{1}+Tv_{2}$. By Hahn-Banach Theorem,
there exists $f\in W'$ such that $f(T(v_{1}+v_{2}))\neq f(Tv_{1}+Tv_{2})$.
On the other hand, $LHS=(Sf)(v_{1}+v_{2})=(Sf)(v_{1})+(Sf)(v_{2})=f(Tv_{1})+f(Tv_{2})=f(Tv_{1}+Tv_{2})=RHS$,
which is a contradiction.

---

2. To show that $T(\alpha v)=\alpha T(v)$ for any scalar $\alpha$
   (i.e., $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ or $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$, depending
   on the scalar field of $V$ and $W$) and $v\in V$:

Prove by contradiction. Suppose the contrary that there exist scalar
$\alpha$ and $v\in V$ such that $T(\alpha v)\neq\alpha T(v)$. By
Hahn-Banach Theorem, there exists $f\in W'$ such that $f(T(\alpha v))\neq f(\alpha T(v))$.
On the other hand, $f(T(\alpha v))=(Sf)(\alpha v)=\alpha\cdot(Sf)(v)=\alpha\cdot f(Tv)=f(\alpha\cdot Tv)$,
which is a contradiction.

---

By 1 and 2, $T$ is a linear map. Lastly, we show that $T$ is bounded.

Firstly, we show that $\sup\{\|Sf\|\mid f\in W'\mbox{ and }\|f\|\leq1\}<\infty$.
Let $v\in V$ be arbitrary, then 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sup_{f\in W',\|f\|\leq1}|Sf(v)| & = & \sup_{f\in W',\|f\|\leq1}|f(Tv)|\\
 & \leq & \sup_{f\in W',\|f\|\leq1}\|f\|\cdot\|Tv\|\\
 & = & \|Tv\|\\
 & < & \infty
\end{eqnarray*}
By Uniform Boundedness Principle, we have that $M:=\sup\{\|Sf\|\mid f\in W'\mbox{ and }\|f\|\leq1\}<\infty$.

Now, we are ready to show that $T$ is bounded and $\|T\|\leq M$.
Let $v\in V$ with $\|v\|\leq1$ be arbitrary. If $Tv=0$, we have
$\|Tv\|\leq M$. Suppose that $Tv\neq0$. Consider the one dimensional
space spanned by $Tv$: $V_{0}=\{\alpha\cdot\widehat{Tv}\mid\alpha\in\mathbb{C}\}$
(or $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$), where $\widehat{Tv}=Tv/\|Tv\|$. Define
$f_{0}:V_{0}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ by $f(\alpha\cdot\widehat{Tv})=\alpha$.
Clearly $f_{0}$ is linear with $\|f_{0}\|=1$. By Hahn-Banach Theorem,
there exists $f\in V'$ such that $\|f\|=\|f_{0}\|=1$ and $f\vert_{V_{0}}=f_{0}$.
We have that 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\|Tv\| & = & f(\|Tv\|\cdot\widehat{Tv})\\
 & = & |f(\|Tv\|\cdot\widehat{Tv})|\\
 & = & |f(Tv)|\\
 & = & |(Sf)(v)|\\
 & \leq & \|Sf\|\cdot\|v\|\\
 & \leq & M.
\end{eqnarray*}
It follows that $\|T\|\leq M$.